# wpa_supplicant but with a double quote in psk phrase

Tags: raspbian, wifi

I have a hidden wifi network that I can't connect to. I'm not totally sure the reason, but I'm guessing it has something to do with the `"` in the psk

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=CA

network={
  ssid="my-ssid"
  psk="satanic"password"
  scan_ssid=1
}
```

I've tried escaping the quotes like `satanic\"password` but no luck. I also tried using wpa_passphrase

---

I retried using wpa_passphrase

1. `wpa_passphrase "my-ssid" | sudo tee -a /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`
2. type in your psk and hit enter
3. `wpa_cli -i wlan0 reconfigure`
4. wait a minute... `ping google.com`

Basically what's in the guide https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/wireless-cli.md

Comment: "I also tried using wpa_passphrase" - did you omit `"` in psk= when you used wpa_passphrase? - if you used actual ssid of "my-ssid" the psk line would look like `psk=624955d137cf2d5e8d6d57925159d6f0ba99dcbc6b52dc17cdc9905c740d1115` ... no quotes

Comment: It's not my actual psk, but I did omit the surrounding `"` and get a similar hex

Comment: Oof. This time wpa_passphrase worked. Maybe I wasn't telling the system to reload wpa_supplicant properly